# write.table unintendedly adds subscript x to header

Tags: r, excel, csv

I have got a comma delimited csv document with predefined headers and a few rows. I just want to exchange the comma delimiter to a pipe delimiter. So my naive approach is:

```
myData <- read.csv(file="C:/test.CSV", header=TRUE, sep=",", check.names = FALSE)
```

Viewing myData gives me results without X subscripts in header columns. If I set check.names = TRUE, the column headers have a X subscript.

Now I am trying to write a new csv with pipe-delimiter.

```
write.table(MyData1, file = "C:/test_pipe.CSV",row.names=FALSE, na="",col.names=TRUE, sep="|")
```

In the next step I am going to test my results:

```
mydata.test <- read.csv(file="C:/test_pipe.CSV", header=TRUE, sep="|")
```

Import seems fine, but unfortunately the X subscript in column headers appear again. Now my question is:

Is there something wrong with the original file or is there an error in my naive approach?

The original csv test.csv was created with Excel, of course without X subscripts in column headers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep using `check.names = FALSE`, also the second time.

Else your header will be modified, because apparently it contains variable names that would not be considered valid names of columns of a `data.frame`. E.g., special characters would be replaced by dots, i.e. `.` Similarly, numbers would be pre-fixed with `X`.